# Finding all integrands

Tags: calculus, probability, analysis

I am trying to characterize all the functions that satisfy the following integrability property

$$ 
\int_{-\infty}^\infty x f(x)e^{-x^2/2}dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f'(x)e^{-x^2/2}dx.
$$

Attempt: if $f$ is even, then the left side is always 0, similarly the right side will be 0 only since the derivative of an even function is odd, so $f'(x)e^{-x^2/2}$ is odd. So the class of all even functions does the trick, is this the best I can do? Additionally, if I just combine the integrals into 1 I get that

$$ \int_R (xf(x)-f'(x))e^{-x^2/2}dx=0$$
which means we need $xf(x)-f'$ to be odd. Is this more general than just the class of all even $f$?

Answer (score 1):

The formula holds for any continuously differentiable function $f$ satisfying the following subgaussian growth condition:

$$ \lim_{\left|x\right|\to\infty} f(x)e^{-x^2/2} = 0. $$

This is very easy to prove. Indeed, by the fundamental theorem of calculus,

$$ \int_{a}^{b} (x f(x) - f'(x)) e^{-x^2/2} \, \mathrm{d}x
= \left[ -f(x) e^{-x^2/2} \right]_{a}^{b}
= f(a)e^{-a^2/2} - f(b) e^{-b^2/2}. $$

Then letting $a \to -\infty$ and $b \to \infty$ proves the desired claim.